# Expected number of White balls followed by a Black ball?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

An urn has *n* *white* and *m* *black* balls that are removed one at a time in a randomly chosen order. Find the expected number of instances in which a *white* ball is immediately followed by a *black* one.

How do I approach such questions? I am clueless about where to even begin!

Comment: Calculate the probability that no white ball is immediately followed by a black one. Then calculate the probability that $1$ white ball is immediately followed by a black one. Then calculate the probability that $2$ white ball is immediately followed by a black one. Repeat this process all the way up to $n$ white balls, and then use the calculated probabilities in order to calculate the expectancy.

Comment: @barakmanos Is this a joke?

Comment: @Did: No. I answered the question of "how to approach such questions and where to begin".

Comment: @barakmanos Except that in this case, computing all these probabilities is a nightmare, with answers depending heavily and in a complicated way on n and m. Did you try to compute "the probability that 2 white ball(s) (are) immediately followed by a black one" for example?

Comment: @Did: No. I didn't.

Comment: @barakmanos Thought so. In such a case, a less authoritative tone than in your first comment would be preferable (hence my first comment).

Comment: @Did: I cannot express tones in a comment (nor in any other written form). OP asked how to approach the problem, I suggested a method which is often used for this type of problems.

Comment: @barakmanos And which fails miserably in the present case. (It is slightly unfortunate that I have to say this myself but the three upvotes on your comment and the ambiguity of your remarks make me feel I have to.)

Comment: @Did: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone). None of the specified categories seem to be even remotely ascribed with any alphabetic (written) structures. It's all about waveform / audio, none of which appears in my comment. So whatever tone you've detected there is your personal interpretation (I respect it BTW, but in this specific case it is plain wrong, I wasn't thinking in any "authoritative tone" whilst writing it).

Comment: @barakmanos I am slightly surprised that you see fit to extend this thread beyond reason (perhaps are you doing this as some kind of damage control operation to hide the fact that your first comment is *false* and *misleading*), but here we go: *as you should be well aware*, the imperative usually indicates that the author is sure that the route they indicate leads to the desired result, otherwise one adds caveats such as "perhaps", "it might work to do so and so", and the like. Your second comment confirms that you were convinced your first was of value, probably because you did not even ...

Comment: ... bother to check it was leading anywhere. Next time, I suggest to think more about the "hints" you want the OP to spend some time on before posting them. Or, add the suitable caveats.

Comment: @Did: As am I (surprised, for the exact same reason).

Comment: @barakmanos I can see that you are willing to discuss everything except the mathematics, hence indeed there is no point in continuing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the white balls $w_1$ to $w_n$. Let random variable $X_i$ be equal to $1$ if white ball $w_i$ is immediately followed by a black ball, and $0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of instances in which a white is immediately followed by a black is given by $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

By the linearity of expectation we have $E(Y)=\sum_1^n E(X_i)=nE(X_1)$.

To find $E(X_1)$, we find $\Pr(X_1=1)$. We have $X_1=1$ if white ball $w_1$ is not chosen last, and is followed by a black. The probability it is not last is $\frac{m+n-1}{m+n}$. Given that it is not last, the probability it is followed by a black is $\frac{m}{m+n-1}$. It follows that $\Pr(X_1=1)=\frac{m}{m+n}$.

Thus $E(X_1)=\frac{m}{m+n}$ and $E(Y)=\frac{mn}{m+n}$.

Answer (score 5):

For $k=1,\ldots,m+n-1$ let $X_k$ be $1$ if the $k$-th ball is white and the $(k+1)$-st ball is black, and $0$ otherwise. There are $\binom{m+n}m$ possible sequences of white and black balls, all of which are equally likely. If we specify that the $k$-th and $(k+1)$-st balls are white and black, respectively, there are $\binom{m+n-2}{m-1}$ possibilities for the remainder of the sequence; why? This means that

$$\Bbb E[X_k]=\frac{\binom{m+n-2}{m-1}}{\binom{m+n}m}=\frac{(m+n-2)!\,m!\,n!}{(m+n)!\,(m-1)!\,(n-1)!}=\frac{mn}{(m+n)(m+n-1)}$$

for $k=1,\ldots,m+n-1$. Now express the number of white balls that are immediately followed by a black ball in terms of the random variables $X_k$, and use [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) to get the desired result.